# How to use the the newly introduced aws_cloudfront_cache_policy resource in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws, hcl

terraform recently implemented the `aws_cloudfront_cache_policy` resource and data source (beginning from aws provider verion `0.3.28` IIRC).
It finally enables `Brotli` compression, and this is why I need to use it, but I am unsure about how to integrate it into the existing terraform codebase, also because I am not exactly sure about the relationship between `aws_cloudfront_cache_policy` and `ordered_cache_behavior`.

1. How to use the `aws_cloudfront_cache_policy` - can I just put it inside my `aws_cloudfront_distribution` resource?
2. What is the difference/relation betwwen the cache policy and the `ordered_cache_behavior`?

Comment: Hi there, I've got same issue, have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 9):

this is how i used aws_cloudfront_cache_policy :

```
data "aws_cloudfront_cache_policy" "cache_policy" {
    name = var.cache_policy_name
}
```

here, `cache_policy_name = Managed-CachingOptimized`

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cfd"{
    default_cache_behavior {
        cache_policy_id = data.aws_cloudfront_cache_policy.cache_policy.id
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I've tried pointing to the data by name and also by id and the output from that data is returning an object with every attribute marked as null.

Comment: Ok, I've passed it by name instead of by ID and it's working... I've done that other day and it wasn't... maybe I misspelled or something, who knows, I'll vote you, thanks!

Comment: @PedroBezanilla not sure if it's because the implementation changed but using Terraform 1.4 and I have to use the id and not the name for it to work

Comment: @Djidiouf well, dunno what to say but trying to update TF. TF had several breaking changes since middle of 2021 so that can be the reason. There's a migration guide too though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use one of the AWS managed policies, namely [`Amplify`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-cache-policies.html#managed-cache-policy-amplify), [`CachingDisabled`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-cache-policies.html#managed-cache-policy-amplify:%7E:text=Amplify-,CachingDisabled,-CachingOptimized), [`CachingOptimized`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-cache-policies.html#managed-cache-caching-optimized), [`CachingOptimizedForUncompressedObjects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-cache-policies.html#managed-cache-caching-optimized-uncompressed) or [`Elemental-MediaPackage`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-cache-policies.html#managed-cache-policy-mediapackage), they all have a hardcoded ID which can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-cache-policies.html#available-managed-cache-policies). This ID can then be used in your terraform :

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cfd" {
    default_cache_behavior {
        cache_policy_id = "658327ea-f89d-4fab-a63d-7e88639e58f6"
    }
}
```

For reference, here are the IDs :

`Amplify` : `2e54312d-136d-493c-8eb9-b001f22f67d2`

`CachingDisabled` : `4135ea2d-6df8-44a3-9df3-4b5a84be39ad`

`CachingOptimized` : `658327ea-f89d-4fab-a63d-7e88639e58f6`

`CachingOptimizedForUncompressedObjects`: `b2884449-e4de-46a7-ac36-70bc7f1ddd6d`

`Elemental-MediaPackage`: `08627262-05a9-4f76-9ded-b50ca2e3a84f`